# Why are the holes different in a magnetizer/demagnetizer box?

Tags: electromagnetism

In a common magnetizer demagnetizer box, the holes for each function are cut differently. Why's that?

I mean, what's the point of that little stairs in the demagnetizer side?

See here: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving the original text, but updated below.

Magnetizing is done by subjecting the tool to a strong magnetic field.  If the field is removed, a residual magnetic alignment remains.  Assuming the field was in a uniform direction, the residual alignment will be lower in strength, but in the same direction.

<strike>The stepped portion contain magnets with different orientations.  As the tool is withdrawn, it passes through areas where the field is in different directions and decreasing strength.  Now there may still be some residual field in the tool metal, but it will not be uniformly in any single direction.  The overall field remaining should be close to zero.</strike>

---

Well, although I found several sites that gave the above information, I believe it to be incorrect.  It certainly *seemed* reasonable that such a configuration would be useful or necessary.

Instead, a [Braniac75](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RazORgAqEUc) video shows that the stairs contain nothing inside.  There is simply a flat magnet in the middle of the unit (and another on the opposite side of the "magnetize" section.  In the demagnetize section, the field is weaker and closer to perpendicular to the tool.  This tends to weaken the magnetization of the tool.

It is possible that some tools may benefit from being held a particular distance from the magnet (which is aided by choosing a stairstep).  But there is nothing inside the stairs, and many tools do not need the precision of them to perform a useful demagnetization.

Answer (score 0):

When you end the degaussing, the last field which touches the tip of the screwdriver leaves it still very little magnetized. Almost parallelly, but may pose a problem if you operate with very small screws. So if you need a better demagnetization, you start at the lowest stairstep, then you go one step further etc. This is similar to the degaussing of old CRTs where the oscillation was slowly subsiding.